# Model Domain separation and Automapper in F#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, n-tier-architecture

I’m new to F# but would like to start building an API with it.

I have previously built C# API’s. In those we layer the architecture between models (being in the controllers), the domain DTO’s in the services and finally in the data layer if there needs to be any persistence.

Between these layers we use Automapper to map the types up and down the layers keeping a clean separation, for example none of our domain objects can have anything null in them (we use a maybe/option) and cater for this in our mappings between the objects.

I have seen examples of building API’s with F# and lots of getting started, but no good examples on architecture. I have also seen people try to use Automapper with F# but it seems shoehorned in and you don't see anyone use it in any of the example tutorials on the net, at least that I have found.

I’m just wondering what people do. Do you use something like Automapper in F#, do you keep a separation between your models and domain DTO’s? do you care? Am I thinking of this in too much of an oop way?

The closest I have come to any help has been on https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/

Comment: Asking for opinion or recommendations for off-site resources is explicitly off-topic on SO because it tends to lead to discussions which doesn't fit the format of SO particularly well. See [help/on-topic] and consider posting the question on a forum or chat instead.

Comment: I've recently read a twitter post by Scott Wlaschin (the author of fsharpforfunandprofit) where he was recommending this repository as a real world example of DDD: https://github.com/atsapura/CardManagement

`This is a "real world" example application, written entirely in F#. The goal is to create a best practice for building applications or at least give a reasonable manual to design one.`

I haven't looked at it myself, but I trust Scott's recommendation and I think it's something that could give you a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m wondering what people do. Do you keep a separation between your models and domain DTO?

It's not that common but we prefer to keep everything manual. We don't create DTOs.

If we want to transfer objects we serialize and deserialize manually without creating additional objects.

DTOs are often used as an aid to serialization, but then you have to do just as much work to write the object <-> DTO mapping and end up with slow, reflection-based, unoptimized serialization.